# Need help with Dementia Hackathon Idea (Professionals experienced with dealing with Dementia patients appreicated!)

Tags: mental-health, brain, prevention, computers, dementia

Me and my team are planning to go to a Dementia based Hackathon early March and since this is our first actual hackathon we were wondering if you could provide some advice regarding our idea. Here's some background on our team and idea.

Our Team: It consists of four people, three of whom are second year Computer Science students and me. We are all beginners - novices at programming and can somewhat use python. Only one of our friends is comfortable enough with Java so we won't be able to use an android app.

Our Idea: To create a game for dementia patients where we help them retain their memories and cognitive function by asking them to select the right picture of something. For example, if they would like to remember what a traffic light is we would get a couple of pictures from google images (one which is the actual traffic light) and ask them to select the right picture. In our theory this will help reduce the regression of cognitive function by helping patients retain their memory through a fun game and possibly stimulate neurogenesis.  Since only of one of us knows Java we are planning to create a Web based game instead of an android app.

Some Issues: We are wondering on what basis we should be asking the questions ( For example, how would we know that most dementia patients need to remember what a traffic light is?). Another thing is I was wondering if we could somehow collect the data from patients playing the game and do some analysis or show it to a professional so they can assess their cognitive function. However, would that be too advanced for us programming wise (we are only beginners programming wise)?

Note: Since this stack exchange is mainly based on health just providing some advice on our idea would help a lot (like how good it is, some tips to make it better, etc.), although if you have some experience with programming and would like to give us advice as well that would also be great. Although I think I will go to SO after to get programming specific advice.

Comment: Great idea. It would actually help a lot. I wish I knew programming to an extent, I would have really loved to help.

Comment: It is a lovely and a very noble idea. However, this is my opinion and the question whether the idea is good is a primarily opinion based one. You could rephrase your question to ask for scientific evidence on what are the most important questions or the most common issues that dementia patients are struggling with, that could be helped by constant repetition through your game. We can't know if something is too advanced for your programming skills, however there are serious ethical implications with collecting data from the patients. That would make an excellent separate question. Best of luck!